# Cannot login into Heroku

Tags: heroku

I have 2FA set for my Heroku account, with Salesforce app.
However, I had to reset my mobile phone last week, and now I cannot login into my heroku account because Salesforce is no longer setup in my mobile, and when trying to login just with my email address and password I'm always requested a Salesforce code.

I've tried to contact Heroku support team by sending an email to support@heroku.com.
I've just got a notification reply saying that a ticket has been created and that I've got an answer to my question. However, I cannot login to see the ticket and the answer!!

Does anyone know how I can recover my Heroku account? Or how can I contact Heroku team without logging into my Heroku account?

Thank you!

Comment: This is exactly what MFA is supposed to do. If you can't provide a token, you can't log in. In the future I strongly suggest that you configure an alternate MFA source and / or save your recovery codes.